# OrientDB returns empty vertices when running multiple instances

Tags: java, database, orientdb

Test should be pretty self explanatory, but anyways, was hunting down this weird bug and after a zillion different test pinpointed things down to this.

The server has to handle data from different realms (eg. from different domains) and it would be best to store them in completely different databases.

For some reason OrientDB returns empty Vertices when another OrientGraph has been opened earlier in some other location.

Hope this is enough meaningless text for StackOverflow's algorithms, here's the code:

```
@Test
public void testLowLevelMultipleRealms() throws Exception {

    String location=("plocal:"+StorageHandler.getBase("test")+"db/orient/");
    String location2=("plocal:"+StorageHandler.getBase("local")+"db/orient/");

    boolean importantVariable=true;
    if(importantVariable){
        //fails
        OrientGraph graph =  new OrientGraphFactory(location).setupPool(1,10).getTx();
        graph.shutdown();

        //also fails
        //OrientGraph graph =  new OrientGraphFactory(location).setupPool(1,10).getTx();

        //also fails
        //new OrientGraphFactory(location).setupPool(1,10);

        //doesn't fail
        //new OrientGraphFactory(location);

        //doesn't fail
        //OrientGraph graph =  new OrientGraphFactory(location2).setupPool(1,10).getTx();


    }
    OrientGraph graph =  new OrientGraphFactory(location2).setupPool(1,10).getTx();

    Vertex v = graph.getVertex("#9:1");
    assertNotNull(v);//passes
    assertNotNull(v.getProperty("title"));//fails iff. importantVariable==true


}
```

Comment: http://t14035.db-orientdb-user.databasetalk.us/running-multiple-database-instances-in-the-same-jvm-space-t14035.html  found this one... tl;dr: OrientDB saves the reference to the last
used database in the ThreadLocal space... no idea how to hack around that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that OrientDB only checks the last folder of the path to check if the db:s are identical. Since both paths ended with db/orient, it got messed up. Adding a redundant but unique subfolder did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `$` instead of `/` and it will works.